# Add Qt 5.14.2 with conan package manager using conanfile.txt and bintray as repo only

Tags: qt, conan

I need to install Qt version 5.14.2 with https://bintray.com/bincrafters/public-conan/
as only authorized repository, i have found the version on the repo at the following adress, https://bintray.com/bincrafters/public-conan/qt%3Abincrafters/5.14.2%3Astable

here is my conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
Qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable
portaudio/v190600.20161030@bincrafters/stable
opus/1.3.1@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

i also added bintray repo with the following command:

> conan remote add bintray https://api.bintray.com/conan/bincrafters/public-conan

but when i conan install it cant find the package:

```
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
compiler.version=10
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

Qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
Qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable: Trying with 'conan-center'...
Qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable: Trying with 'bintray'...
ERROR: Unable to find 'Qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable' in remotes
```

Answer (score 0):

Conan packages are in lower case, so you need to write `qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable` in your conanfile.txt file.

When I try to install package as you noted I get:

```
ERROR: Requested 'Qt/5.14.2@bincrafters/stable' but found case incompatible 'qt'
Case insensitive filesystem can't manage this
```